# how to calculate interest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

We have a web app that among other things, allow users to leave a cash balance on their account (which can be cashed out anytime or used to purchase items on the site).  Users can withdraw and deposit funds to their account anytime.  It was never intended for it, but we now have users who leave large sums on their account and they're now requesting that we provide some interest on their account balance which is totally reasonable.  Problem is we have no idea how to calculate interest on an account where users can withdraw and deposit funds anytime, but all the banks obviously do it so I was wondering if there's a standard way (or ruby gem) to calculate interest.  Any pointers or help is greatly appreciated.

The db table setup is pretty simple.

User has one Account

```
Accounts(user_id, balance)
```

Account has many activities

```
Activities(account_id, type, amount, description, created_at)
```

Where type can be either "Deposit" or "Withdrawal".

Comment: It depends on your compounding (daily, monthly, quarterly) and when the interest is added.  Have you decided how you want to do this?  A reasonable way is to add in the interest monthly, but compute it on the average daily balance for the month.

Comment: @duffymo - i finished my phd 5 years ago.  no more school and homework for me :)

Comment: @Ray Toal: We're thinking of doing it monthly, i.e. a monthly cron job that goes through all accounts and deposits interest payments.  Not sure how to calculate the average daily balance (yet) but makes sense.  As long as someone can't deposit a large sum and withdraw it 2 mins later to get a large interest we'll be happy with it.  Thanks.

Comment: You finished a Ph.D. and you don't know how to calculate interest?  My post requires little more than reading ability.  I got a Ph.D. 19 years ago, and I haven't stopped learning since.  I think your attitude is a grave error.

Comment: @duffymo - i'm happy to learn and know how to calculate interest.  we were just wondering if there's a standard way the banks do it or if there's a gem that already does it for you. by homework i thought you mean't this post was a school project - i think i misunderstood.

Comment: Why would the formulas be different for banks?

Comment: @duffymo i can think of countless examples where solutions you learn on your own, in school, or by googling ends up being not sophisticated enough in real world situations.  Plus if there's a plugin or gem that already does this for you, I'd rather learn from their solution rather than re-solve the problem from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer on what interest calculation to use I agree with Ray Toal that you are going to have to ask your client what interest calculation to use and what their payment scheme is like.

Usually speaking, financial institutions that offer interest on a chequing account are calculated with compounding interest calculated daily [at the close?] of each business day and paid monthly at the end of each month by a deposit directly into the account.

Notably, banks and other financial institutions will tell their clients the interest rate on a yearly basis (APR) and not the interest rate per-day. It is an elementary mistake that I have made in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Exonio gem: https://github.com/Noverde/exonio.

This gem implements some of the Excel financial formulas, including the Interest calculation that you are asking for.

From their docs:

> What is the interest part of a payment in the 8th period (i.e., 8th
> month), having a $5,000 loan to be paid in 2 years at an annual
> interest rate of 7.5%?
>
> > `Exonio.ipmt(0.075 / 12, 8, 12 * 2, 5_000.00) # ==> -22.612926783996798`
>
> So, in the 8th payment, $22.61 are the interest part.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11035060)

Comment: You are right @RenéVogt ... I will update the answer. Thanks ;)