# ruby on rails: how can i modify the code by using iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iterator

im using switch case to add interest of every month and new amount added every month.the below code shows the recurring deposit calculation for 1year likewise i did for 5year.
can anyone tell me how to cut short this code? how to use **do..end**?

```
before_save :calculate_interest1
def calculate_interest1
case no_of_year
when 1
self.total = (amount * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon2 = total + amount + amount
self.total1 = (mon2 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon3 = total1 + amount + mon2
self.total2 = (mon3 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon4 = total2 + amount + mon3
self.total3 = (mon4 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon5 = total3 + amount + mon4
self.total4 = (mon5 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon6 = total4 + amount + mon5
self.total5 = (mon6 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon7 = total5 + amount + mon6
self.total6 = (mon7 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon8 = total6 + amount + mon7
self.total7 = (mon8 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon9 = total7 + amount + mon8
self.total8 = (mon9 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon10 = total8 + amount + mon9
self.total9 = (mon10 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon11 = total9 + amount + mon10
self.total10 = (mon11 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.mon12 = total10 + amount + mon11
self.total11 = (mon12 * interest_rate * day / (no_of_days_in_year * 100)).round
self.Final = total11 + mon12
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Or you could just look up the algorithm for calculating compound interest and implement it in Ruby....

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to calculate interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964427/how-to-calculate-interest)

Comment: I don't know what you're using this code in, but I would strongly discourage you from using `round` in almost any financial calculations. Or floating points, for that matter...

Comment: @asQuirreL:for my calculation i need to include round

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: im doing monthly calculation.for every month interest should be added with amount(100 in 1st month,next 100 rs in 2nd month etc) for that only i did like this.i just want to know how to use this code in do..end

Comment: The answer to your question is in the duplicate I closed against. Your basic problem is you should have one function that calculates the interest on a balance, and then another function which calls it x times. Keeping the intermediate values so you can see how the balance will/has gone up over the period, simply requires shoving the result in to an array as you loop through the months. PS pay attention to asQuirrels point about floats, they are a serious problem in currency calculations. Even more so in something like this, every discrepancy will be compounded...